# Calculating whitespace given list of rectangles?

Tags: computer-science, rectangles, computer-vision

It's part of a software application, but should be irrelevant for this. The main thing is the code generates a set of rectangles (with each having x, y position and width, height).

Some rectangles are inside other bigger ones.

What I need to do is to calculate the whitespace between them (for example, if two rectangles are separated, the whitespace is the distance between them, but if a rectangle is inside of another, then the whitespace is the space around that inside rectangle).

Is there any simple way of accomplishing this?

EDIT: here is a picture of what I need to do https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3VGN.jpg

Thank you

Comment: It is not clear. You should make a figure with an example showing the different cases.

Comment: Do you want the minimal whitespace separation over all pairs of rectangles? Do any of your rectangles intersect? What do you want if they do?

Comment: I have edited the question and added a link with an image of what I need to do. And also, as described on the photo, some rectangles overlap

Comment: Can't you just check for the minimum distance between all pairs of parallel lines?